# setVisible() vs getChildren.add()/remove() vs toBack()/toFront()

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Sometimes all 3 methods are different ways to achieve the very same thing. When would you use one over the other? What are the performance differences? Are there other quirks to them?

Comment: Those methods do completely different things! Only under special circumstances do they behave similar. Just use the one that does the correct thing, whether it's modifying the order of the children, modifying adding/removing elements from the child list or hiding a element.

Comment: I only claimed they achieve the same thing. Making a Node visible or not to the user. Im interested in the specific differences especially in terms of performance. If I add or remove the node as a child node, set its visibility property or just hide it behind another node in my stackpane, for the user it will look the same, but what actually happens in the background is not. And I want to know especially the performance aspects for applications running on very limited hardware.

Comment: @404KnowledgeNotFound Why are you worrying about performance here?Do you have any evidence any of these options degrades the performance of your application? If so, explain that in your question. If not, you are [prematurely optimizing](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29) for performance and essentially trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. Just choose the option that makes the most sense for your actual requirements.

Comment: Well its a very specific thing, I have a Java Monkey 3D Engine running in an offscreenbuffer which displays a warehouse where a crane goes over plates and a VBox with all the plates on that space pops up and dissapears once he leaves. Each frame from the 3D-engine I write into a Bytebuffer which is written into an WriteableImage in my FX-Application. At the Bytebuffer is where the JME thread and the FX-Thread meet and in order to ensure data integrity I have a synchronized over it. And that whole thing is running on very bad passive cooled HTPC inside Cranes, with 2x1Ghz CPU.

Comment: cont. And what I have noticed is that the FX-Thread and JME Thread block each other alot and FX-Thread activity leads to big stutters and slowdowns. Especially talking about things like Nodes popping up or not. I am aware that this is not the core of the problem and I have asked about a real solution in the JME Forums as the issue is too specific for stackoverflow. But I wanted to explore this part too not only for my problem but also out of general curiosity. Might have a app one day that shows and hides hundreds or nodes per second, at that magnitude it would be good to know what is fastest.

Comment: Just to add, FX itself actually experiences the slowdown. Due to the thread mingling, pulses are simply not send out in time and FX framerate becomes incredibly poor. Its running on very slow hardware and I simply want to shave off every little bit of load. We are talking about PCs here where resizing the taskmanager leads to up to 50% cpu usage by the taskmanager thread.

Comment: It doesn't really seem like any of the performance problems you describe are related to the issue about which you ask in the question. I would be surprised if there is a sizable performance difference between any of the three different pieces of functionality you describe; showing or hiding hundreds of nodes in any of these ways just involves setting properties or adding/removing references from a list; each of those in turn mark the layout as invalid so the next pulse will repaint (that is the same in all three scenarios). None of that seems performance intensive.

Comment: `toFront()/toBack()` calls `getChildren().add()/remove()` at least 4 times. to`(Front/Back)` is a convenient method for re-arranging your `Node`s, since the `Node` at index `0` is the one showing to the user. `setVisibility()` well does a different thing in terms of children ordering but in terms performance they all trigger the same/similar set of codes to achieve the final result,-(recalculating the parent and child for the final output).. so if i were you i will be superstitious and go with one -Node arranging is costly when you have a lot, so its better to remove and add later

Comment: This thread is very relevant, thank you for bringing up that. I run a JavaFX application with dozens of thousands of nodes in it. So handling nodes is a very hard task and sometimes it becomes a true pain, so every bit counts in here. Spring does an amazing job when handling application performance, but the main player here clearly is JavaFX. In order to contribute to the discussion, I'll give an example when handling nodes by removing them, setting them as not visible, and bring to the front/back:

Comment: An AreaChart has multiple points in it, which are nodes. Create an Observable list to store its data. In that observable list, load it with thousands of nodes and refresh the area chart every second with a Thread or TimeLine. The application performance is very poor at that time (even setting the chart nodes as not visible and caching all nodes/AreaChart itself). Setting the AreaChart as not visible or placing it behind some node with toBack() doesn't change performance at all, although when removing the AreaChart from its parent, it causes the application performance to instantly increase

Comment: My guess is that the application UI thread doesn't have to render it anymore, causing the application performance to increase